# Finding a counter example for Minkowski's integral inequality for $p=\infty$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory

Dear All,

As we know that this following Miskowski's integral inequality is true for $1\leq p<\infty$

$
[\int_{S_1}|\int_{S_2}F(x,y)d\mu_1(x)|^pd\mu_2(y)dy]^{1/p} \leq \int_{S_2}[\int_{S_1}|F(x,y)|^pd\mu_2(y)]^{1/p}d\mu_1(x)
$

I think that Minkowski's integral inequality is not right for the case $p=\infty$. And I am trying to find a counter-example when $p=\infty$ but I have not had luck. Does anyone know any counter example for that case OR if you know how to prove that it is still right. Thank you very much and I really appreciate your help.

Phi

Comment: The wikipedia says that it IS true for $p=\infty" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality), and who are we to argue?

Comment: Dear Igor Rivin,

I don't see the proof in Wikipedia. I don't believe any thing with out the proof on Wikipedia. Do you know how to prove it?

Comment: I'm confused. I see expressions of the form $[\ldots]^p$ in you formula. How should I interpret them when $p=\infty$?

Comment: The wikipedia says that the statement should be modified "in the obvious way" for $p=\infty.$ Presumably to replace the usual integrals by essential suprema (or garden variety suprema for continuous functions).

Comment: In any case, if you still have questions, I think they would belong better on http://math.stackexchange.com where you will find many people able and willing to clarify.

Comment: Dear Yemon Choi,

I believe that this question is hard enough to ask on Mathoverflow since I took a long time to look at many books in my math library and there is no book saying about the case $p=\infty$, I also follow the proof in case $1\leq p<\infty$ but I cannot get it when $p=\infty$. I also don't see any proof if it is true. 

Comment: Phi, as Andre points out, what you wrote down doesn't make sense for $p=\infty$. There is an analogue for $p=\infty$: 
$$\bigg\|\int f(x,y)\; dy\bigg\|_\infty\le \int \big\|f(x,y)\big\| _\infty\; dy$$
This is not in every analysis book, but it is in Folland's Real Analysis (p. 194).

Answer (score 1):

Presumably we want:
$$
\sup_{y \in S_1} \left|\int_{S_2} F(x,y) d\mu_1(x)\right|
\le \int_{S_2}\sup_{y \in S_1} |F(x,y)| d\mu_1(x)
$$
where $\sup$ is actually essential supremum with respect to $\mu_2$ on $S_1$.

Notation a bit confusing, since here (unlike the wikipedia version) $\mu_1$ is on $S_2$ and $\mu_2$ is on $S_1$.